# Images can't be resolved in Sass when using CSS modules

Tags: css, webpack, webpacker

I'm using Webpacker in my Rails project and want to use CSS modules to obfuscate the CSS classes for my CSS and SASS files in my components.

`./config/webpack/development.js` looks like:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

const environment = require('./environment')

/// Use CSS modules and obfuscate CSS class names
const cssRule = environment.loaders.get('css')
const sassRule = environment.loaders.get('sass')
const cssLoader = cssRule.use.find(loader => loader.loader === 'css-loader')
const sassLoader = sassRule.use.find(loader => loader.loader === 'css-loader')

cssLoader.options = Object.assign(cssLoader.options, {
  modules: true,
  localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
})

sassLoader.options = Object.assign(sassLoader.options, {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
  })
///

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

Now this works fine for just the CSS and SASS and obfuscates them fine... however when I reference something such as an image inside my CSS I get the error:

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--2-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--2-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--2-4!./app/javascript/components/menu/main.scss
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'background.png' in '/Users/cameron.drysdale/Projects/webpack_test/app/javascript/components/menu'
>        @ ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--2-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--2-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--2-4!./app/javascript/components/menu/main.scss
>   7:785-805

Inside `main.scss` I have:

```
.element {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url('background.png');
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**If I turn off the CSS modules, then it works fine...**

What's causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to use [resolve-url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader) to have the `url` resolve correctly